# How are imports in Python handled?

Tags: python, import

Most of Programming Code i saw import keywords are only written in the Header of the file. Is it a good idea to do imports just before using executing Methods from a module?

Example import in Header:

```
import json

def importCache(): 
    import json
    json.load(open("text.txt"))
```

Example late import :

```
def importCache(): 
    import json
    json.load(open("text.txt"))
```

Is there an optimization process when loading all modules as a bunch?

Comment: Yes, thats definetly a duplicate! thx